# Bash: A multiword variable breaking curl

Tags: bash

I am having a small problem with in bash.

I have this rather ugly line

```
curl -u "$USER:$PASS" --request POST --data '{"title": "'$BRANCH_NAME'", "body": "'$DESCRIPTION'", "head": "'$OWNER':'$BRANCH_NAME'", "base": "develop"}' https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO_NAME/pulls
```

Where most of these variables are single words the $DESCRIPTION can be more than one but it seems that it breaks the line.

Is there some way to make $DESCRIPTION not break the curl command when it has more than one word in it?

Answer (score 11):

Using [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) *here-doc*, that will be safer for (y)our brain(s) :

```
curl \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-type:text/json" \
    -d@- \
    "https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO_NAME/pulls" <<EOF
    {
        "title": "$BRANCH_NAME",
        "body" : "$DESCRIPTION",
        "head" : "$OWNER:$BRANCH_NAME",
        "base" : "develop"
    }
EOF
```

- `-X` switch is the same as `--request`
- `-d` switch is the same as `--data`
- you can replace `d@-` by `-d@/dev/stdin` if exists.
- `@` for `-d` switch means *read from a file*

The simple and proper solution =)

Answer (score 3):

You should put your variables within "" quotes. Like:

```
curl -u "$USER:$PASS" --request POST --data '{"title": "'"$BRANCH_NAME"'", "body": "'"$DESCRIPTION"'", "head": "'"$OWNER"':'"$BRANCH_NAME"'", "base": "develop"}' "https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO_NAME/pulls"
```

Alternatively, you could (probably even should) do:

```
data="$( printf '{"title": "%s", "body": "%s", "head": "%s:%s", "base": "develop"}' "$BRANCH_NAME" "$DESCRIPTION" "$OWNER" "$BRANCH_NAME" )"
curl -u "$USER:$PASS" --request POST --data "$data" "https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO_NAME/pulls"
```

Comment: I like the alternative, except for the double quotes around the `"$(...)"` part; I think they're going to wreak havoc on the interpretation of the `printf` arguments.  Simply omit the outermost double quotes.

Comment: No, they will not. Omitting is probably safe but I prefer to always quote.

Comment: Thank you. Bash quoting will be the end of me. And I am taking your second example to heart.

Answer (score 0):

Since `$DESCRIPTION` can be multiple words, it must be surrounded by double quotes, thus:

```
curl -u "$USER:$PASS" --request POST \
     --data '{"title": "'$BRANCH_NAME'", "body": "'"$DESCRIPTION"'", \
              "head": "'$OWNER':'$BRANCH_NAME'", "base": "develop"}' \
     https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO_NAME/pulls
```

That's a trifle non-obvious, but the `"'"$DESCRIPTION"'"` section has a double quote inside the single quoted value for `--data`; then the single quote is terminated (temporarily), then there are double quotes around `"$DESCRIPTION"`, then there's the start of a new single quoted section, and the first character inside is a double quote.

For consistency and future-proofing, you should also surround the other variables similarly:

```
curl -u "$USER:$PASS" --request POST \
     --data '{"title": "'"$BRANCH_NAME"'", "body": "'"$DESCRIPTION"'", \
              "head": "'"$OWNER"':'"$BRANCH_NAME"'", "base": "develop"}' \
     https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO_NAME/pulls
```

Try to avoid both single and double quotes in all the shell variable values; you will have nightmares getting it right if you have to worry about such quotes.