# curl used in tfs Couldn't resolve host

Tags: curl, tfs, ftp

I'm using curl in a step on a TFS build. The step generates a cUrl command to upload some files to a ftp location.

I simplified the command to the least simple example that gives the same issue:

```
curl --stderr - -T {"helloworld.txt","helloworld2.txt"} ftp://10.32.4.2/CI/Workspace/
```

it says:

> curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'helloworld2.txt'

while

```
curl --stderr - -T "helloworld.txt" ftp://10.32.4.2/CI/Workspace/
```

does, as expected, upload the file to the ftp location.

Comment: That's a quoting issue of the shell. Which one are you using? (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14863609/21567) for a related issue). As such it has nothing to do with TFS.

Comment: Powershell I suppose... Well actually it has something to do with quotes. changing `{"helloworld.txt","helloworld2.txt"}`in `"{helloworld.txt,helloworld2.txt}"` works. But the first one is how TFS generates the command.

Comment: Are you building the command line for curl, or is TFS doing it (from a build step shipped by MS or 3rd party)? If the later, you should see if you can report a bug there, otherwise just build your command line like you (now) know it works ;-)

Comment: It is generated by a build step (the cUrl build step :) ) already on TFS.

Comment: Ah OK, sorry about that: I readded the `TFS` tag. You might want to report an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate the `cURLUploader.ps1` script on your agent. It was under $agentPath\tasks\cURLUploader\1.0.0\

Change line 54 from

```
$uploadFiles = '{"' + [System.String]::Join('","', $foundFiles) + '"}'
```

to

```
$uploadFiles = '"{' + [System.String]::Join(',', $foundFiles) + '}"'
```

I submitted this as a bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2202

Comment: You can mark it as answer so that other people has similar issue could see this.